# Python 3.3 argparse error after compiling to exe with cx_freeze

Tags: python-3.3, cx-freeze

Trying to compile a Python 3.3 application but running into problems after compiling it to win32 exe using cx_freeze on Windows 7.

Example:

**Test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import argparse
import tkinter.messagebox


cl_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Test app Command Line Parameters')
cl_parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 1.0')
cl_parser.add_argument('-s', '--show', help='show simple message box',
                       action='store_true')

cl_args = cl_parser.parse_args()

if cl_args.show:
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title='Simple Message', message='Hi There')
```

**Cx_Freeze Script**

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

import shutil

#Remove Build/Dist Folder Before Compile
args = None
print('Removing Old Folders...')
try:
    for args in sys.argv:
        if args.find('build_exe') != -1:
            shutil.rmtree('build', ignore_errors=True)
        elif args.find('bdist_msi') != -1:
            shutil.rmtree('dist', ignore_errors=True)
except:
    pass
finally:
    del args
    print('Folders Removed')

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'includes': 'atexit',
        'include_msvcr': True
    }
}

executables = [
    Executable('Test.py', base=base, targetName='Test App.exe')
]

setup(name='Test App',
      version='1.0',
      description='Test App',
      options=options,
      executables=executables)
```

After the successful compile I try a few command line tests on the exe:

```
Test App.exe -s (This successfully shows the messagebox)
Test App.exe -h or TestApp.exe --version (Fails with AttributeError: 'NoneType' Object has no attribute 'write')
```

Is there a way that I can make it so that this will work? I am trying to create a PyQt4 application and don't want to have to compile this as a console application.

Your feedback would be appreciated

P.S. Yes I know i've included an example with tkinter but this is for demo purposes only.